# How to clear application data other than shared preference And database

Tags: android, caching, clear-cache

I want to clear cache of application (Not shared preference and database) pro-grammatically.
I searched many question but those only give way to clear all the data but I want shared preference and database untouched.

Thank You.

Main issue:-- I am working on android Bluetooth related application which connects a device. so if i search device and try to connect. If connection fails and user again clicks search button then application don't show in b

Comment: Cache data? Do you mean "cacheDir()"?

Comment: Any data application creates other than shared preference and database...

Comment: Well, you need to keep track of what you have cached and clear it yourself.

Comment: What if without track??

Comment: Are you want delete paired device list?

Comment: I am not sure but after searching again and again device device found frequency decreases...that's what my issue is....

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear, "what if without track". You are writing the code, of course you know what you cache and not.